# Is there a starting ground to implement Facebook's BigPipe?

Tags: php, facebook

Reference: http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=389414033919

They said they build it in PHP and Javascript, which is great, but is there any code that makes this available for the public? Whether it is the same as theirs or a similar project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Here's an open source implementation](http://www.juhonkoti.net/2010/10/01/open-bigpipe-javascript-implementation) of this concept.

Answer (score 2):

[Edge Side Includes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_Side_Includes) are something *along* the same lines, instead of composition in the browser, it happens in the proxy server.

If you are interested in this alternative you can check out a nice [implementation in symfony 2](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/http_cache.html#using-edge-side-includes).

Answer (score 0):

I made a version of Facebook's BigPipe for the Play Framework: https://github.com/brikis98/ping-play